# Update/Notify HTML from backend asynchronously without AJAX polling

Tags: php, ajax, html, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am developing a dashboard for CRM, where admins can view/process all orders.
Requirement:
Whenever a user places an order from website/mobile app, one dedicated PHP file is called from which the user data is inserted into the Database.Now I want to notify the online admin about the new order without refreshing the page.

I know it's very easy if you use AJAX polling, but I don't want to use AJAX polling. And I tried PHP Websocket also by referring [this](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket) tutorial, but unfortunately that doesn't work on live server.

Kindly let me know if there is any workarounds or any technology I can implement to achieve my requirement.

I am using HTML5 frontend and PHP for backend.

[image: My Requirement]

Comment: Visit http://socket.io for a easy to use socket server

Comment: You could register a service worker and send messges to the client via google cloud messaging (gcm)

Comment: @Jonasw, How does that(Service worker) work ? I am using PHP

Comment: a service worker is basically javascript that runs in the background. You can use it to register to google cloud messaging. Your php script just needs to send the message to google and google sends it to the browser. This is quite fast and because google polls the servers regularily this will not consume your bandwidth

Comment: Sounds interesting, Do you have any sample codes or references/tutorials  ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en

Comment: Unfortunately that works only on chrome. Isn't it ?

Comment: It works on every modern browser, however firefox uses its own endpoint, so you dont have to register to google

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager

Answer (score 1):

You should select a WebSocket framework like socket.io. There are many advantages of not using web sockets directly due to web socket  limitations in some browsers and platforms . Socket.io frameworks like socket.io addresses this issue by being backward compatible. 
Socket.io original back-end implementation runs on node.js. So unless you don't want to have node js, look for a socket.io php wrapper like elephant.io.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and check.

Comment: Yes, sure.. let me implement and test it first. :)

Comment: Great . Looking forward to hear how everything went with .

Comment: This package seems to require NodeJS 0.6.5+. Can you please clarify me on that.

Comment: That is correct. These are php wrappers and internal build in engine is node.js .